# Access website hosted over LAN from mobilephone

Tags: lan

I am developing a webpage and would like to see how it looks on mobile browsers, preferably the real thing and not some emulator.
So I thought of making my locally hosted site available over LAN. I managed to do that and can access it fine over the WLAN from another computer. However if I try the same address from an Android, IOS or Blackberry device I get "Webpage not available".

Why is this? How can this be solved?
All devices in question access the LAN wirelessly if it matters.

Comment: On your mobile phone, have you disabled mobile data and enabled wifi?

Comment: Yes. I've had mobile data completely off on my htc and iphone for the last 2 years. And I also made sure global pages are working so that it wasn't anything funny like they were out of reach from the router.

Comment: What does your http server log say?

Comment: I served local pages to mobile phones a number of times and never had any problems.  I guess yours stems from a misconfiguration of your mobile phone, wireless LAN, LAN or web server.  But more details are needed to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the WLAN access point and all the devices (including the web page server) are on the same network, check that:

1. You can access the server hosting the site using it's IP address in your WLAN network,
2. You do not have a proxy configured on your mobile devices.

I regularly test internal web server development by loading the page on my mobile device connected via my WiFi access point.

If you still can't connect, maybe there is a setting in either your web server machine's firewall or the WiFi router routing that is messing you around.